# Make the occurrences of a string bold

Tags: text-processing

Now, this is a homework question, but I have simply no idea how to go about solving it. It'll  be great if someone could guide me about how to go about it.

I've been given a large string of Upper Case Alphabets in a .txt file. I basically need to find two given sub strings(3-4) characters and change the font (or make it bold, or highlight it) of the sub string that is between the two given sub strings.

Comment: Could you give an example of the text file and the search strings?

Comment: The text in the file is one big continuous string that looks like `GCGGCCCAGGCCCGGAACCTTCCCTGGTCGTGCGCCATATGTAAGGCCAGCCGCGGCAGGACCAAGGCGGCGGTGTCAGCTCGCGAGCCTACCCTCCGCGGACGGTCTTGGGTCGCCTGCTGCCTGGCTTGCCTGGTCGGCGGCGGGTGCCCCGCGCGCACGCGCAAAGCCCGCCGCGTTCCCAGACCCCAGGCCGCGCTCTGTGGGCCTCTGAGGG....` 
And the string that I need to find  is something like `AGT` or `AG`. 2-3 Characters long

Comment: What should you use for a solution or are your free to choose? Second, when you have `AGTAGTTAGAG` what should match? `T` or `AGTTAG`?

Comment: I'm free to use any solution. I'm using OpenSuse 12.3. and in case of the given string `AGT` should match.

Comment: You mean `AGTT` should be highlighted?

Comment: Search 'Awesome bioinformatics' or just 'Awesome bash' on github and a wealth of ATCG one liners and parsers come up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @slm I used the `grep --color` command  along with  a `regex`. Here is my final solution that worked perfectly for me.

```
 grep --color=always -P '(?=ATG).*(?=GT).*(?=TAG)' data.txt
```

Comment: Clear and simple.

Answer (score 1):

The finding the strings should be relatively easy using a tool such as `grep`. Given this is a homework question can you provide anything you've researched thus far? I don't want to take the learning opportunity away from you but would like to help too.

Take a look at `grep`'s man page. I would be inclined to try solving this by creating a file with the matching strings, let's call it `patterns.txt`.

```
$ cat patterns.txt
AGT
AG
```

Once you put the strings you're looking for in this file you can use `grep` to do both the color highlighting and also the matching. The switch, `-f` allows you to match patterns that are provided by a file, like so:

```
$ grep -f patterns.txt sample.txt
```

[image: ss of grep output]

I highly encourage you to read the `grep` man page and check out some of the other switches it has to offer. Also try playing around with grepping for different strings and try using some of `grep`'s other switches.

Feel free to follow up in comments if you have any follow-up questions, Unix is all about experimenting.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I didn't know about `grep`. After much experimenting I finally found my solution by using a regular expression with the `grep --color` command and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @fts - glad to hear it! Welcome to U&L hopefully we'll see you back asking + answering Q's. 8-).